# Select2 not updating when data array altered

Tags: reactjs, jquery-select2

I am using [react-select2-wrapper](https://github.com/rkit/react-select2-wrapper) which has the same functionality as select2.

I'm trying to change **All** to the text of whatever `basisList` is selected. I am able to correctly update it to **Users (ID)** using `componentWillMount()`.

My problem is, if I change the `basisList` that is selected to `machines` which calls `this.updateResolutionText()` does not cause select2 to re-render. ***I can see that my state has been updated correctly, however select2 isn't updating.***

What am I missing? I would think that by updating `this.state.resolutionOptions` that my select2 component would automatically update, thus displaying the new text.

```
this.state = {
    resolutionOptions: [
        { text: 'All', id: 0, value: 'all' },
        { text: 'Month', id: 1, value: 'Monthly' },
        { text: 'Day', id: 2, value: 'day' },
        { text: 'Day-Hour', id: 3, value: 'Day-Hour' },
        { text: 'Hourly (0-23)', id: 4, value: 'hourly' },
        { text: 'Day of Week', id: 5, value: 'dow' }
    ]
}

componentWillMount() {
    this.updateResolutionText()
}

componentDidUpdate() {
    // this returns correctly {text: 'Machines', id: 0, value: 'all'}
    console.log(this.state.resolutionOptions[0]);
}

updateResolutionText() {
    let basisList = [
        {text: 'Users (ID)', id: 0, value: 'users'},
        {text: 'Machines', id: 1, value: 'machines'}
    ];
    let options = this.state.resolutionOptions;
    let comparison = 'users';

    if(basisList) {
        for(let i = 0; i < basisList.length; i++) {
            if(basisList[i].value === comparison) {
                options[0].text = basisList[i].text
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    this.setState({ resolutionOptions: options });
}

<Select2 className="form-control"
         ref="resolution"
         data={this.state.resolutionOptions}
         defaultValue={0}>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not update the state directly

```
    this.state = {
    resolutionOptions: [
        { text: 'All', id: 0, value: 'all' },
        { text: 'Month', id: 1, value: 'Monthly' },
        { text: 'Day', id: 2, value: 'day' },
        { text: 'Day-Hour', id: 3, value: 'Day-Hour' },
        { text: 'Hourly (0-23)', id: 4, value: 'hourly' },
        { text: 'Day of Week', id: 5, value: 'dow' }
    ]
}

componentWillMount() {
    this.updateResolutionText()
}

componentDidUpdate() {
    // this returns correctly {text: 'Machines', id: 0, value: 'all'}
    console.log(this.state.resolutionOptions[0]);
}

updateResolutionText() {
    let basisList = [
        {text: 'Users (ID)', id: 0, value: 'users'},
        {text: 'Machines', id: 1, value: 'machines'}
    ];
    let options = [...this.state.resolutionOptions];
    let comparison = 'users';

    if(basisList) {
        for(let i = 0; i < basisList.length; i++) {
            if(basisList[i].value === comparison) {
                options[0].text = basisList[i].text // HERE
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    this.setState({ resolutionOptions: options });
}

<Select2 className="form-control"
         ref="resolution"
         data={this.state.resolutionOptions}
         defaultValue={0}>
```

This line:

```
options[0].text = basisList[i].text // HERE
```

so you can avoid that doing a new object

```
let options = [...this.state.resolutionOptions];
```

Comment: I've updated as you suggested, but it still didn't resolve my problem. I'm able to inspect my state before/after the change and I can see that it's correct.

Comment: Can you share your example in a CodePen or similar?

Comment: I tried to post it in StackBlitz but apparently it's not pulling in the external library properly. You can see the code here, but it's the same as what I have posted above. https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-4djpfl